# 2007 Honda Accord EX-L V6 - Can I use 2 different strut brands in front and back?

Tags: honda, accord, struts

I recently bought a used 2007 Honda Accord EX-L V6 and I think I need to change the struts. I have been looking around online for struts and there are so many different brands.

I nailed it down to Monroe brand and here is the one that I'll be buying:

- [Monroe 171372 QUICK-STRUT Complete Strut Assembly $135.99 (x2)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IJGANQI)
- [Monroe 172123L Strut Assembly $121.99](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FJT6X58)
- [Monroe 172123R Strut Assembly $121.99](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FJT61F0)

I also found [Gabriel G57056 ReadyMount Complete Strut Assembly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0076UN73O) for $82.

**Can I use Monroe for the front struts and Gabriel for the rear struts?** Should I stick with the same brand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use different brands on the front and rear. Some high performance vehicles do this to get specific handling needed. In your case, it may not be a choice for performance, but it should be acceptable.

It would not be a good idea to alternate brands side-to-side.

Source: [Can I mix and match different kinds of units?](http://www.shockwarehouse.com/site/faq.cfm)